# add 'description' to Pydantic schema when using pydantic.dataclasses

Tags: python-3.x, swagger, openapi, pydantic

`Pydantic` supports generating OpenApi/jsonschema schemas.  When using Pydantic's `BaseModel` to define models one can add `description` and `title` to the resultant json/yaml spec.

```
class DescriptionFromBasemodel(BaseModel):
    with_desc: int = Field(
        42,
        title='my title',
        description='descr text',)
```

and this is carried over to the schema: `DescriptionFromBasemodel.schema_json()`

```
{
    ... schema title, description, type top-level ...
    "properties": {
        "with_desc": {
            "title": "my title",
            "description": "descr text",
            "type": ...
       ...
```

however, I cannot determine how to plumb this using `pydantic.dataclasses` which my application must use to play nicely elsewhere.  you can add `metadata` to stdlib `dataclass` `Field(...)`s, but pydantic does not use them (?)

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import field

@dataclass
class DataclassWithDescription:
   a_field: int = field(metadata=dict(
       description="descr text"))
```

and no `description` is generated output using `DataclassWithDescription.__pydantic_model__.schema_json()`

Answer (score 7):

I find this works (note usage of Pydantic's Field),

```py
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class DataclassWithDescription:
   a_field: int = Field(description="descr text")
```